# How can i get HttpClient to work with NTLM in a pcl with android

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, httpclient

have the following which works on Win10 phone in a pcl. 
But i cannot get the same code to return OK on samsung s7 with android 7.0
project is xamarin forms.
nuget for system.net.http is 2.2.29.
I've include the same nuget in my UWP for the win10 phone and android projects.
i've also changed the user to include be "domain\user", "domain@user", "user@domain"

```
var httpClientHandler = new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler()
{
    Credentials = credentials.GetCredential(new Uri(location), "NTLM")
};
```

I've tried and alternative to setting the httpClientHandler.Credentials.

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredentials("user", "pass", "domain");
var location = "http://apps.mysite.com/api#/doit";
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler{
    Credentials = credentials
}
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler, true))
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
    try
    {
        var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(location);
            if (httpResponseMessage.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //handle error
            }
            else
            {
               //do something
            }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {}
    finally
    {}

}
```

another strange thing. when i run this on android, the code hits the await httpclient.getasync(location); 
and the immediately jumps to the finally.

I hava a simple form with username & password Entry Fields, plus an OK button.
all three controls are bound to a viewmodel. the OK button via an ICommand.

this code and the view live in the PCL. which has a reference to Microsoft.Net.Http.
I have Android and Universal Windows Xamarin forms builds that consume the PCL.

Android Properties. Default httpClient, SSL/TLS Default. supported arch armeabi, armeabi-v7a;x86

Android Manifest: Camera, flashlight and internet

```
private bool calcEnabled = false;
private ICommand okCommand;
private string message = string.Empty;
private string validatingMessage = "Validating!";
private string unauthorizedMessage = "Invalid Credentials!";
private string authenticatedMessage = "Validated";
private bool validating = false;
public ICommand OkCommand => okCommand ?? (okCommand = new Command<object>((o) => clicked(o), (o) => CalcEnabled));

protected async void clicked(object state)
{
    try
    {
        Validating = true;
        Message = validatingMessage;
        var credentials = new 
        System.Net.NetworkCredential(Helpers.Settings.UserName, Helpers.Settings.Password, "www.domain.com");
        var location = "http://apps.wwwoodproducts.com/wwlocator#/information";
        var httpClientHandler = new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Credentials = credentials.GetCredential(new Uri(location), "NTLM")     };

        using (var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
            try
            {
                var httpResponseMessage = await 
                httpClient.GetAsync(location);

                if (httpResponseMessage.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Message = unauthorizedMessage;
                }
                else
                {
                    Message = authenticatedMessage;
                    Messenger.Default.Send<bool>(true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Message = unauthorizedMessage;
            }
            finally
            {
                Validating = false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: 401 unauthorized

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in code. If you can temporary create user name and password I can try to see what is wrong. You can delete those credentials in few hours

Comment: unfortunately that won't happen, this runs behind alot of security on our intranet which IT manages. Thanks anyway

Comment: I'll see if i can get any further error information

Comment: Can you host the same service in DMZ somewhere?

Comment: @muscleman71 Show the encapsulating method and how it is called.

Comment: @YuriS let me ask the Network admin, but i doubt it very much.